# Subtracting two shapes in Sketch produces odd result

Tags: sketch-app

I'm trying to subtract two shapes in Sketch 3.0.3. One outer oval and one inner oval, with the inner one being a partially cut out oval shape (shown in green).

This is before:
[image]

And this is after subtracting the two shapes as selected in the sidebar:
[image]

The result I expect is for the green shape to be subtracted. Instead the transparent part of the green shape is subtracted as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are just missing one step after subtract, you need to flatten the form (the result of the subtraction) because unlike Illustrator Sketch treats "Pathfinder-functions" (sorry come from Illustrator ;) ) like a mask. To make them to one form  Flatten them to one and you can subtract again.

Comment: That was not immediately obvious to me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I made a short video showing how you could make any type of shape or graph using the Sketch. Hope this comes to help!

https://youtu.be/nBhZswq3pgM